# Sass font family add double quote to format. And I don't need it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, sprockets

I have a problem.

I have this stylesheet source

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova';
  src: font-url(/assets/proxima_nova_reg-webfont.woff) format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

The compiled version by sprocket is

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima-nova';
    src: url(/assets/proxima_nova_reg-webfont.woff) format("woff");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
```

The double quote in format are an issue for me because when I use in my rails template

```
=File.read "#{Rails.root}/public#{stylesheet_path('amp/application', host: nil)}"
```

The result is

```
@font-face{
 font-family:'proxima-nova';
 src:url(/assets/proxima_nova_reg-webfont.woff) format(&quot;woff&quot;);
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal
}
```

And the stylesheet looks corrupted

To solve I'm using

```
    =File.read("#{Rails.root}/public#{stylesheet_path('amp/application', host: nil)}").gsub(/[\"]/,"'")
```

But is not a good solution

Comment: `src: url('/assets/proxima_nova_reg-webfont.woff') format('woff');` ?

Comment: is font-url but it doesn't matter... quote is converted to double quote

Comment: `format(quote(woff))` ?

Comment: @llobet the same double quote. I need css with single quote